# ZPL multiple lines without wordwrap

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I am trying to create a block in which a variable length of txt can be printed on a label, depending on the length of the txt, creating one or more lines of course, this is no problem using ^FB or ^TB, but here's the catch: I want to disable word-wrap. Is this somehow possible?

```
^FT20,130^FB550,3,,^FH^FDDescription: $_3000DE$^FS
```

Comment: How is this supposed to work? You want to autogenerate multiple lines of text, but without wordwarp. How do you tell the printer then to print a new line?

Comment: With FB I set the maximum width of each line within the textbox. When the end of each line within that FB is reached, the next character needs to be printed on a new line, no matter if a word is cut off and continued on the next line.

Comment: Please provide an example block of text to demonstrate how the text is supposed to wrap.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the [ZPL Programming Guide](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) doesn't mention any possibility to turn of the automatic word-wrap functionality of the `^FB` or `^TB` command.

So the answer to your question is a simple: **No, it's not possible.**

Answer (score 0):

However, it does allow for the wrap to happen outside of the label which is what will work.
In my example below the `999` prints the wrapped text off the label (6x4 label):

```
^FO65,370^A0B,40,30^FB520,2,999^FD<Company Address1 Company Address1>^FS
```